# Upgrade database. Can I alter tables or need to create new?

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade

I'm using a database in my application which is currently on the Google Play. Now I'm releasing an update and have added a new column to an existing table. Looks like I need to use `onUpgrade()` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. I'm just wondering if I need to recreate the whole table, which leads to backup/restore (which is complex) process, or I can just alter it on upgrade? How shall I handle upgrade in the code? Is it just enough to implement `onUpgrade()` method? Might be any good example? Really appreciate your input, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can alter table . No need to create it again .

```
    private static final String ALTER_USER_TABLE_ADD_USER_SOCIETY =  "ALTER TABLE user_table ADD user_society TEXT";
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        if(newVersion > oldVersion)
        {
            db.execSQL(ALTER_USER_TABLE_ADD_USER_SOCIETY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are these newVerstion and oldVersion? where did they come from?

Comment: It is in onUpgrade() Method . Old and new are database version

Comment: yes, because onUpgrade method is called when you change the version of database.